# Rails SQL in controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, x-editable

I'm using `Xeditable` and `RABL` in a Rails app.

I have a `workorder` that belongs to a `workgroup`.
I want to assign the `workorder` to an `employee` in that `workgroup`.

I'm using this as the source in the `Xeditable`:

```
data-source="/employees.json?workgroup=<%= workorder.workgroup.id%>"
```

And this is the code I'm trying in the `employee` controller:

```
  def index
    @employees = Employee.order(:first_name)
    @employees = Employee.joins(:empgroups).where(:workgroup_id => params[:workgroup]) if params[:workgroup].present?
  end
```

This is the SQL that gets generated:

```
SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" INNER JOIN "empgroups" ON "empgroups"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" WHERE "employees"."workgroup_id" = 2
```

The issue is the WHERE should be `WHERE "empgroups"."workgroup_id" = 2

How do I change this line of code?

```
@employees = Employee.joins(:empgroups).where(:workgroup_id => params[:workgroup]) if params[:workgroup].present?
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested hash syntax:

```
@employees = Employee.joins(:empgroups).where(
  empgroups: { workgroup_id: params[:workgroup] }
) if params[:workgroup].present?
```

Comment: Adding an `if` at the end of a long statement, especially a multi-line one, seriously degrades readability. It'd be better to put the statement inside an `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Employee.joins(:empgroups).where(:empgroups => {:workgroup_id => params[:workgroup]})
```

The `:workgroup_id` is actually an attribute/column on a joined table, and not on the base table that you are querying from, so you need to specify where that column is located during the where clause.

Remember that in a pinch you can also type in SQL for the where clause, but will also have to remember to properly reference the right table.

```
Employee.joins(:empgroups).where("empgroups.workgroup_id = ?", params[:workgroup])
```